# Get some value from store procedure Cannot

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0

I input username & i wanted to get all details as output.First i show you in php code,

```
$strSQLUSER="SELECT * FROM User WHERE username='".addslashes($MessageArray[0])."' AND state!='1' AND state!='4'";

$result_user=odbc_exec($conn,$strSQLUSER) or die("Could not connect to database");


$huntername   = stripslashes(odbc_result($result_user,"name"));
$huntlicense = stripslashes(odbc_result($result_user,"license"));
```

Then i use my .net coding for that.here is the part of the coding.

```
 private void MooseSeenInput(string MobileNo, string Date, string odd, params Array[] msg_arr)
    {

        controller = new UnitsController();

        DataSet ds = controller.GetUserDetails(username);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            //get username & License
            string user=ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
            string license= ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["license"].ToString();
        }
```

Then i wrote Stored Procedure for this... but i'm unfit for this procedure,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.

 @UserName varchar(50),
 @License  varchar(50) OUTPUT
 AS
 BEGIN

 Select * FROM
 Users
Where UserName = @UserName & State ='1' & State= '4'

END
```

--exec GetSMSUserDetails_SP

Additionally here i have added sqldataprovider part

```
 public override DataSet GetSMSUserDetails(string UserName)
    {
        return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(ViltraConnectionString, GetFullyQualifiedName("GetSMSUserDetails_SP"),UserName);
    }
     #endregion SMS
```

Comment: PHP's `AddSlashes` won't protect you from SQL Injection - please see [this](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string) for an example.

Comment: here i convert php to c#

Comment: That's fine, just saying for future reference :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `And` instead of `&` for string concat in sql server.

Remove `Out Parameter` from SP because you are returning records.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetSMSUserDetails_SP

 @UserName varchar(50)
 AS
 BEGIN

     Select * FROM
     Users
    Where UserName = @UserName and State Not IN ('1' ,'4')

END
```

SP with Output param.

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Getsmsuserdetails_sp @UserName varchar(50), 
                                         @License  varchar(50) output,
                                         @name  varchar(50) output
AS 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT TOP 1 @License = License, @name = name 
      FROM   Users 
      WHERE  UserName = @UserName 
             AND State NOT IN ( '1', '4' ) 
  END
```

Comment: is thisonce are correct ? UserName varchar(50),
@License  varchar(50) OUTPUT   >> In the UserName also at sign there

Comment: I given username as a parameter.

Comment: If you want a single column output as a result then use OUTPUT parameter else simply use as I have mentioned.

Comment: I added some coding to my original post.please look

Comment: I wanted to pass UserName & getalldetails(Select *) from the Users table whether state is Not equal to 1 & 4.After the results i wanted to assign username & license No to another variables..The my coding way is correct ?

Comment: Use NOT IN instead of IN. Please let us know if there are two fields name and username in Users  table.

Comment: Use the first sp posted by me and use the .net code posted by you. it should work. Please let us know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you want the query to be..

AND State **NOT** IN ( '1', '4' )  ? since, you have used **!='1'** in the fist code you posted?

Also, consider only returning the fields you need instead of using '**SELECT ***' which returns all fields.

Comment: I wanted to pass UserName & getalldetails(Select *) from the Users table whether state is Not equal to 1 & 4.After the results i wanted to assign username & license No to another variables..The my coding way is correct ?

Comment: Romil has edited his code to be NOT IN now, that should work.